Can I install the mltable package into Anaconda?
I need to use the mltable package to create mltable files for Azure Machine Learning from CSV files.
I have Anaconda installed, but there does not seem to be a way to install the mltable package, since it is in PyPI but not anaconda.org. This seems like a common problem in general.
What can I do here?

You can install it using pip install mltable. what is the blocker you facing?

Thank you! That worked. I am not familiar with these tools, and was thinking I had to use conda to install.

Giving it an answer so that it will help community to find better solution.
You cannot install mltable from Conda Forge, as the package is not available in any Conda Forge repository.
I also tried installing it in an Azure Machine Learning notebook with Python SDK 2 kernel and encountered the error below.

Thus, the possible solution is to use the pip command.
pip install mltable
